# How to add new stylesheet to custom theme in functions.php?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am starting with wordpress so I'm trying to add a stylesheet to my custome theme. I'm facing errors in my code I don't understand.

I tried different samples of code but still vscode is giving me weird errors.

In the code below, vscode give me 4 errors:

1. "'(' expected.", it wants an opening parenthesis after 'action',
2. "')' expected.", same with the closing parenthesis,
3. "'{' expected.", now it wants an opening bracket after 'action',
4. "'}' expected.", finally it wants closing bracket before the code.

The code:

```
<?php 

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'template_enqueue_scripts' );
function template_enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_register_style('CSS', get_template_directory_uri() .'style.css');
    wp_enqueue_style( 'CSS');
}

?>
```

I'm lost, how can I fix these errors so that my style is applied correctly?

Comment: I don't get what your error is. Everything looks fine except a slash after `get_template_directory_uri()`. Something like this `wp_register_style('CSS', get_template_directory_uri() .'/style.css');` .

Comment: Thanks! Also the problem disappeared, very weird.

Comment: May be it had something related to the path to file. Happy to know you are all set :)